# Get difference between two dates in years - without months - without days

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using the following function in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to get difference between two dates:

```
public static int getDiffYear(Date first) {
    int yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween(new DateTime(first), new DateTime()).getYears();
    return yearsBetween;
}
```

The date supplied to function is: 0001-10-02 (YYYY-MM_DD)

I get the difference as 2013 as checked against today, however I find the correct result should be 2012. Because the day still is 01.

I have a separate function in pure Java, with the desired result:

```
public static int getDiffYear(Date first) {
        Calendar a =  Calendar.getInstance();
        a.setTime(first);
        Calendar b = Calendar.getInstance();
        int diff = b.get(Calendar.YEAR) - a.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) > b.get(Calendar.MONTH) || 
                (a.get(Calendar.MONTH) == b.get(Calendar.MONTH) && a.get(Calendar.DATE) > b.get(Calendar.DATE))) {
            diff--;
        }
        return diff;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why 2014 - 1 should be 2012. *Sans* means without.

Comment: You should also make sure to be fully aware of the consequences of the Proleptic Gregorian calendar. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Julian_and_proleptic_Gregorian_calendar_dates

Comment: Okay I am confused, I am reproducing a pure Java function above. I want an equavalent in Joda. Not in terms of do my homework but I am not accounting for anything except for Years.

Comment: ANd I am sorry about the naming conventions which have been messed.

Comment: By the way, Joda-Time is "pure Java" too.

Comment: I meant without using a library.

Answer (score 2):

Joda will take days into account with `yearsBetween`.  Try this:

```
public static int getDiffYear() {
    LocalDate firstDate = new LocalDate(1, 10, 2);
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate();
    int yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween(firstDate, today).getYears();

    return yearsBetween;
}
```

It will return 2012 as of today (2014/10/01).  This indicates something is happening in the conversion from `java.util.Date`.

EDIT: This is due to what Marko Topolnik [mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Julian_and_proleptic_Gregorian_calendar_dates).  When you do `new DateTime(first)` you are getting a `DateTime` of 0001-09-30.

Answer (score 1):

The `Years` utility class is going to only check the difference in years. If you need to keep the days into account, you should use the `Days` class and recalculate the result to years.

Comment: I dont need to takecare of the days, only years.

Comment: Yes, but you want to take into account what day of the year it is. The Years class is going to calculate the difference between year 1 and year 2014. What you want is to verify that it is 1 october 2014, so it hasn't been 2013 years, but tomorrow it will be.

Comment: So any hints in that regard?

Comment: Also if done in days, I think considering leap years would be a pain.